# How to convert a JavaFX ImageView to InputStream

Tags: java, javafx, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have an `ImageView` that contains an image, what I need is to make a getImage() of the `ImageView` and convert it to an `InputStream`. This is the code that I have:

```
try {

    File fileImage = new File(ivImage.getImage());

    InputStream isImage = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(fileImage);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way to get the `ImageView` image and convert it to `InputStream` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you get bytes from an image and create ByteArrayInputStream?

```
ImageView view = new ImageView();
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(view.getImage(), null);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", outputStream);
    byte[] res  = outputStream.toByteArray();
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(res);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it worked.  But there is a way to use JavaFX instead of java.awt.image.BufferedImage (AWT)?

Comment: I tried to google it but there are lots of solutions for android and I know nothing about it (I am not sure if you write this code for android or not). You need to convert Image to byte array and then create ByteArrayInputStream, so you can try _ImageView to byte array_ search request